# Is there a way to filter sql execution plans by specific operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a great bunch of sql server statements that run on sql server 2008
I try to inspect its execution plans.
Actually it generates a great deal of execution plans.
I want to show only the execution plans that have a specific operator(s).
e.g I want to get the execution plans that have Table Scan operator.

Any way to do something like this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered this a while back ([Searching for table/index scans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540192/searching-for-table-index-scans/))

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'),
CachedPlans
(
ParentOperationID,
OperationID,
PhysicalOperator,
LogicalOperator,
EstimatedCost,
EstimatedIO,
EstimatedCPU,
EstimatedRows,
PlanHandle,
QueryText,
QueryPlan,
CacheObjectType,
ObjectType)
AS
(
SELECT
RelOp.op.value(N'../../@NodeId', N'int') AS ParentOperationID,
RelOp.op.value(N'@NodeId', N'int') AS OperationID,
RelOp.op.value(N'@PhysicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS PhysicalOperator,
RelOp.op.value(N'@LogicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS LogicalOperator,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost ', N'float') AS EstimatedCost,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateIO', N'float') AS EstimatedIO,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateCPU', N'float') AS EstimatedCPU,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateRows', N'float') AS EstimatedRows,
cp.plan_handle AS PlanHandle,
st.TEXT AS QueryText,
qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan,
cp.cacheobjtype AS CacheObjectType,
cp.objtype AS ObjectType
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
CROSS APPLY qp.query_plan.nodes(N'//RelOp') RelOp (op)
)
SELECT
PlanHandle,
ParentOperationID,
OperationID,
PhysicalOperator,
LogicalOperator,
QueryText,
CacheObjectType,
ObjectType,
EstimatedCost,
EstimatedIO,
EstimatedCPU,
EstimatedRows
FROM CachedPlans
WHERE CacheObjectType = N'Compiled Plan'
and
(PhysicalOperator = 'Clustered Index Scan' or PhysicalOperator = 'Table Scan' 
or PhysicalOperator = 'Index Scan')
```